# Zend Framework 3: How to use and (push-)UPDATE progressbar?

Tags: javascript, zend-framework3

currently I have issues using the progress-bar in a MVC-Zend-Framework 3 application.
I followed excatly the instructions given in the [Zend-documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-progressbar/intro/).

But my problem is, that I see an empty progress bar, which is not updated, while my long-running-php-script is working (no file-upload but a calculation job which takes around a couple of minutes). It seems, that the update function for the progressbar is not called....

Some snippets:

a) the index.phtml file
(Remark: Compared to the documentation I changed the position and size of the iframe to check the debugging output of my long-running-php-script)

```html
$this->headTitle('Test-Page');

$this->h1('Test-Page');
?>
<style>
#long-running-process {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;

    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#zend-progressbar-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;

    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#zend-progressbar-done {
    width: 0px;
    height: 30px;

    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function Zend\ProgressBar\Update(data)
 {
     document.getElementById('zend-progressbar-done').style.width = data.percent + '%';
 }
</script>

<div>
    This page demomstrates the use of the Zend Progressbar:
</div>

<div id="zend-progressbar-container">
    <div id="zend-progressbar-done"></div>
</div>

<iframe src="long-running-process.php" id="long-running-process"></iframe>
```

b) part of the long-running-php-script:

```
$this->adapter = new Adapter\JsPush();
$this->progressBar = new ProgressBar($this->adapter,0,100);
//[...]
// in a long running while-loop is this code:
$this->progressBar->update(round($progress));

//end in the end:
$this->progressBar->finish();
```

As said, the progressbar is not changed but stays with a zero value. Unfortunately I was not able to find any working examples in the internet.

Furthermore I am interested to "push" not only the value but maybe some status messages to the progressbar (as mentioned a little bit in the documentation), but the corresponding syntax is not clear for me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in the meantime, I can answer the question by myself :-)

The [description](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-progressbar/adapters/#jspush-adapter) of the JsPush-adapter stated, that the default value for the update-method is

> Zend\ProgressBar\Update

and as shown in my question, the method in the script had exactly this name. When I renamed the method to something like

```html
function ZendProgressBarUpdate(data)
```

and added after the initilization of the adapter the following line:

```
$this->adapter->setUpdateMethodName("ZendProgressBarUpdate");
```

everything worked as expected.